# Linear Algebra - Finding point Q using distance

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $P$ be the point $(-3, 2, 1)$. Suppose that the point $P_0(1, -3, 6)$ is  $1/8$  of the way from $P$ to $Q$.
Find the point $Q$.

---

I was thinking of using the midpoint formula for this but that would take a lot more work. I also thought the distance formula would be more appropriate but I don't exactly know how to implement it. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

$$\vec{PP_0}=\frac 18\vec{PQ}$$
$$\implies$$

$$x_0-x_P=\frac 18(x_Q-x_P)$$

$$\implies$$

$$x_Q=8x_0-7x_P=29$$